# Easiest way of slicing a 2 dimensional data going through values using rows then next cloumn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a very large data that look like this:

```
[[1, 4, 5, 7],
[8,9,33,17,],
[6,0,15,21,]]
```

and I want to convert it to a specified equal chuncks of rows. starting by all rows of first column, then second column.. which would look something like this if number of chunkcs required is 6

```
[[1,8],
[6,4],
[9,0],
[5,33],
[15,7],
[17,21]]
```

I have written this code which takes in the data array and number of chunkcs (rows) required, and I believe that the code is badly optimized since it takes a long time ( I have a huge set of data ):

```
def ssliices(oldData, nChunck):
    data = []
    # =====store all data in a single row:
    for j in range(oldData.shape[1]):
        for i in oldData: 
            data.append(i[j])
    #=======       
    nSamples = len(data)//nChunck   # number of data for each row     
    final = np.empty(shape=(nChunck,nSamples))
    for i in range(nChunck):
        initalStartIndex = nSamples * i
        final[i,:] = data[initalStartIndex:initalStartIndex+nSamples]

    return final
```

Comment: Would nChunck * nSamples always equal len(data)? What happens if nchunks = 5 in above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear whether your array is a true numpy array, but I proceed as though it is.

```
a=np.array([[1, 4, 5, 7],
[8,9,33,17,],
[6,0,15,21,]])
```

We transpose to get the right ordering of the data, then flatten, then reshape the flattened array into the correct shape

```
a.T.flatten().reshape(-1,2)

array([[ 1,  8],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 9,  0],
       [ 5, 33],
       [15,  7],
       [17, 21]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If nChunck * nSamples will always equal len(data), you can simply reshape the transposed array to the required shape. If that is not the case, you will need to slice the array based on the nChunks and reshape the sliced array. Something like,

```
def ssliices(oldData, nChunck):
    # Assuming oldData is a numpy array
    a = oldData.T
    nsamples = a.size//nchunks
    # Only required if nChunck * nSamples != len(data) 
    a_sliced = a.ravel()[:(nsamples*nchunks)]

    return np.reshape(a_sliced, (nchunks, a_sliced.size//nchunks))

a = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 7],
[8,9,33,17,],
[6,0,15,21,]])

ssliices(a, 5)

array([[ 1,  8],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 9,  0],
       [ 5, 33],
       [15,  7]])
```